# Access data submitted to localhost inside of wkwebview, Star Web PRNT and iOS SDK for printer

Tags: javascript, ios, localhost, wkwebview, thermal-printer

We are currently working on an integration for a Star Micronics thermal printer. They have a Javascript SDK which allows you to build the request and send it to a native application. Attached below is sample code.

We plan to include this inside a WK Webview on iOS. Currently using Swift. The question is, if the javascript is sending the data to a localhost url, how can we get this data from the native end within the app.

Here is the URL for javascript SDK: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/mannualfolder/en/_sampleProgram.htm

Here is code sample, will not work on fiddle, needs to be ran elsewhere such as within the Star WebPRNT app. https://jsfiddle.net/e4r8a6z7/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=e4r8a6z7

```
var url              = 'http://localhost:8001/StarWebPRNT/SendMessage';
var papertype = 'normal';


var trader = new StarWebPrintTrader({url:url, papertype:papertype});
```

Comment: You need to provide the data via an accessible web server.  You can't provide the data from a `WKWebView`.  If you have the data in your app then you probably should send the data via IP or BLE

Comment: The data is to be submitted within the Webview itself. There is no way to send this data to the native application via the Webview? 

They currently have a browser app out called Star WebPRNT that does what we need, but it is branded as Star Micronics and we need our branding. Additionally, we can use work arounds, don't necessarily need to send to a localhost if another way is possible

Comment: My understanding of how WebPRNT works is that you pass their app the URL that contains the print instructions.  That app then fetches the contents/instructions and passes it to the printer via IP or Bluetooth.  You can't host such as URL on the mobile device itself since as soon as their app comes to the foreground, your app is suspended.  If you want to print directly from your app then you just make a direct connection to the printer.

Comment: So the way it currently works from what they told me, is the Star WebPRNT app that they provide is a Webview. It takes the data submitted to the app and sends it to the bluetooth printer. So we were trying to do the same, but where I was confused was, in their app the data is submitted to the localhost url. Does this mean they have a local server within the app? I guess I am just confused as to how they are able to get that data in their app from the Webview

Comment: The documentation for that you linked to shows an external web server and the URL that you use (at the bottom of that documentation) shows that you need to pass the URL for that external web server to the WebPRNT app.  I guess they then fetch the javascript from that remote web server and run, which submits the instructions to the web server they are running in the WebPRNT app.

Comment: If you want to print directly from a native app then you should use the native iOS SDK for Swift or Objective-C that is available from Star.